# Column with the same values across rows as a MultiIndex Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas df like below:

| Id | Period | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 20 | 60 |
| 1 | 4 | 30 | 70 |
| 2 | 3 | 40 | 80 |
| 2 | 4 | 50 | 90 |

How can I use Period as additional column, like this: (to have Period 3, 4 as separate columns and under each column with periods I have subcolumns Value1 and Value2)?

[image: MultiIndex DF]

Comment: This is a basic pivot, you just need to specify the index and columns, which puts everything else into the values argument: `df.pivot(index='Id', columns='Period')`. Then you can clean it up a bit by adding on a `.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)` to get the ordering you want

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pivot` then `swaplevel` and `sort_index`

```py
out = (df.pivot(index='Id', columns='Period', values=['Value1', 'Value2'])
       .swaplevel(0,1,1)
       .sort_index(axis=1))
```

```
print(out)

Period      3             4
       Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2
Id
1          20     60     30     70
2          40     80     50     90
```